# Would it be considered as rude as full name is not visible?

Tags: print-design, typography, critique, design-principles

I want to make *two* printed photos with text on them, for a marriage gift. Something like this:

[image]

But both must be placed together to give complete meaning. The couple name is DEVANSHU (male) and AMRIYA (female) (slightly changed, concept remains same). Here's a rough sketch:

[image]

The idea is to combine both names and show a *connection* between them. I would use **M** to connect both frames (fortunately I guess I'm lucky that **M** also stands for Marriage). Of course, I'll need to work for M to make it not look bad, so that it gives feel of both **N** and **M**.

Now, I can read the full name of female (AMRIYA). But for male, only DEVAN is visible, in following way:

DEV**A[N/M]RIYA**

I feel like it can be a good idea for the gift, where they can place it on wall side by side.

But I have one doubt that might destroy this idea. Male name is not fully visible.

Are there any real world examples where similar things have been done? If no, would it be considered rude? Should I add small full names also in the bottom corners to *fix* that?

Comment: I don't wish to offend, but I don't think it's a great grift. Do you know  a great many couples with their names hanging on their wall? Just my opinion. I'd smile, thank you, then put the thing in the back of a closet.

Comment: Okay, but would it be rude? E. G. a crooked finger tips in a hand illustration?

Comment: I have no idea if it would be "rude". That's all in the opinion of someone receiving such a gift.

Comment: I don't think It's possible to answer this question as it's opinion/location/culture background-based and has nothing to do with to graphic design. I'd personally consider somethig like a second-hand gift a _rude_ gift, but my name on a wall? More like kitch, never would've put it on a wall. But I know someone who has their portrait on a wall. So once again, it depends on a person. P.S. I think money is the best gift to a young couple, anything else will end up in a closet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We in the far west can see this as a trick to present something in a trivial way, like "they belong together". But nothing quarantees that the Devamriyas 10000 miles away make the same interpretation. They can have totally different habits, beliefs and traditions. You as an urban person may have alienated from these things which determine what is right and what is wrong. The law can be seen only as a tool to put into action something which is felt to be right. And if the law doesn't support what the feeling demands it can be ignored.

So, you must be 100% sure you understand what the local culture says of your trick, do not think that we in the far west know the answer. Ask locals, ask those who have lived their childhood in the same environment and have the same ethnical background as the Devamriyas. The worst possible scenario that I can imagine: In the next night a crowd rushes into your home and take you. You have captured a respected man into a cage and cropped him, he's now only a half a man. You must be punished. And see: "worst" is only my opinion. What will possibly happen can be seen as a justice, a way to restore man's honor.

I guess user Scott has already given an answer in his comment how your trick would be treated in urban western culture. The message would be taken, thanked and hidden.

Comment: They studied in US.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to join N and M then i guess putting the whole name ''DEVA[N/M]RIYA'' in one frame would be great.

there will be two frame bars in between the join of N+M according to your idea...... so it wont be aesthetic.

the whole purpose is to make the couple happy and it's their NAME...one of the most beloved aspects of human life... so if their name is not legible the whole purpose will be gone...

decision is yours.